# Why FormData stops working when adding multiple content?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using croppie to crop and upload an image to my server and the problem is that when I send the cropped image alone, it works perfectly, but when I want to add another information in a FormaData, all stops working...

The original code that WORKS is this one:

```
$uploadCrop.croppie('result', {type:'canvas', size:'viewport'}).then(function(resp){
    $.ajax({
      url: "upload.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { "image": resp },
      success: function (data) { alert("ok"); }
    });
});
```

And the PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST['image'];
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$imageName = time().'.png';
file_put_contents('img/profiles/'.$imageName, $data);
?>
```

This works perfect, the image is saved properly, but when I use this code below with the same PHP file, stops working...

```
      var cropped_img;
      var nameInfo = "Someone";
      var mailInfo = "anything@mail.com";
      $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {type:'canvas', size:'viewport'}).then(function(resp){cropped_img = resp;});
      var parametros = new FormData();
      parametros.append('name', nameInfo);             
      parametros.append('mail', mailInfo);
      parametros.append('image', cropped_img);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        data: parametros,
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) { alert("ok") }
      });
```

The first time I tried, didn't work, so I added cache, contentType and processData, and started saving the file, but is a kind of empty or corrupt file...

Anyone know how can I fix this?!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "kind of empty"?

Comment: I find the image file in the folder with the correct name and extension, but when I download it and open it, the image viewers don't shows anything, and I cannot open it with any photo editor neither... and 0 bytes size.

Comment: Do You See Any Error In Your JS Console?

Comment: If I remove contentType and processData false for both, I get "Illegal invocation uncaught type error"